# Passing range parameters to Crystal object

Tags: vb6

I have an already designed Crystal report which has two parameters: `AccountNo` and `Transaction_Date`.

`AccountNo` is a discrete value

`Transaction_Date` is a date range parameter (Start of the range and end of the range).

I intend to pass this parameters through my vb6 code. **My attempt to do that displays/exports for me blank report.**

Here is the Code:

```
    Set objCrystal = New CRAXDRT.Application
    objCrystal.LogOnServer "pdsodbc.DLL", "SMARTHR", sTrDSource, CStr(strUserName), CStr(strPwd)

    Set objReport = objCrystal.OpenReport(App.path & "\Reports\CPSMPA.rpt", 1)

    objReport.DiscardSavedData
    objReport.ParameterFields(1).AddCurrentValue (v_ACCNO)
    objReport.ParameterFields(2).MaximumValue = v_ENDDT
    objReport.ParameterFields(2).MinimumValue = v_STATDT
    ''objReport.ParameterFields(1).AddCurrentRange(v_STATDT,v_ENDDT,crRangeNotIncludeUpperLowerBound)
    ExportReportToPDF objReport, (App.path & "\Reports\Emails\" & v_ACCNO & "MPA.pdf")
```

I believe the way I am passing the parameters is not right.

Comment: What values are in v_ENDDT and v_STATDT ?

Comment: v_ENDDT and v_STATDT are date type variables holding End date and Start Date respectively.

Comment: Eugene, the tags are important because many people on SO follow tags they are familiar with. So by tagging it with both VB6 and VB.Net you may confuse people and cause them to go on to something else. I would remove whichever tag is not applicable - OR explain in the question how both are relevant if indeed they are.

Comment: Ought to have tagged vb60 in trying to remove VB.NET, if you can remove for me will appreciate Sir.

Comment: Looks like you've done it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my way out by changing how i pass the values to the date range parameter. It might help another person. Find it below.

objReport.ParameterFields(1).AddCurrentValue (v_ACCNO)
  objReport.ParameterFields(2).AddCurrentRange v_STATDT, v_ENDDT, crRangeIncludeLowerBound